# I would like to copy the layout of a webpage, but I don't understand this code

Tags: css

This is my first question on Stack Overflow.
I would like to copy the awful [**EDIT** awesome: my keyboard went wrong] horizontal layout of this webpage:
http://www.google.com/nexus/10
so I used Firebug to know how the code is made.
They use a CSS propriety to make some images persistent horizontal, even if you zoom out till the text isn't longer readable (example: the section called "Hangout").
This is the code of the part I'm interested in (directly from Firebug):

```
.nexus-10 .hangouts {
background: url("/nexus/images/n10-hangouts-bg-blur.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center, url("/nexus/images/n10-hangouts-bg-tile.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 #F2DAC0;}
div, a, li {
border-color: #EFEFEF;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0;
}
body {
color: #555555;
font: 300 15px "Roboto",arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Anybody has got any idea?
Help me please

**EDIT**
Ok I was unclear but I don't know how to say it: I want to know what that "no-repeat scroll" means and how can I use it in my webpage. Don't need to say I'm not good in HTML programming and I don't know exactly CSS

Comment: *"copy the __awful__ horizontal layout"*. Err, why would you like to copy something you don't like? Furthermore, what have __you__ tried to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. Perhaps set up a jsfiddle and show us what you have tried. Based on what you have posted I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: What's your question?  Please make it more specific than _"here's what I'm interested in"_.

Comment: Those are jsut a comma spearated list of background images for the element. Not much to it really.

Comment: There's nothing proprietary about multiple background images.

Comment: If you're no good at CSS, you simply need to reference some good documentation:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you - [CSS Backgrounds](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

The no-repeat means it wont repeat the background image

Scroll property sets whether a background image is fixed or scrolls - [Scroll](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry my question was unclear and unuseful.

Comment: Your welcome & Don't worry :D This is a good place to learn!